# Splunk nested queries

Tags: splunk

I have the following query on splunk

```
index="cusomerIndex" source=*client-api* "pending customer approval"
```

This query gives me the following result

```
msg: pending customer approval for customer1`
```

I have another query on splunk

```
index="orderIndex" source=*order-api* "email notification sent"
```

this query gives me the following result in the customer field

```
customerId: customer1
msg: email notification sent
```

I'm trying to come up with a query where I get all the cutomers who had a result for "pending customer approval" but don't have a result for "email notification sent".  I'm not an expert in splunk so not sure how to do it.

Comment: Your pending customer approval query doesn't return a customerId, so `index="cusomerIndex" source=*client-api* "pending customer approval" | rex " for (?<customerId>[^\s]*$)" | table customerId` should give you the customer ID of the pending customer approval result.  And then `index="cusomerIndex" source=*client-api* "pending customer approval" | rex " for (?<customerId>[^\s]*$)" | table customerId | search NOT [search index="orderIndex" source=*order-api* "email notification sent" | return customerId]` should give what you want.

Comment: Let me know if that works, and if not I can help you figure out why.  A couple places to look: https://answers.splunk.com/answers/37565/not-subsearch.html and https://answers.splunk.com/answers/483528/how-to-get-subsearch-to-return-a-result-which-is-n.html

Comment: Thanks for this, however it does not work, it fetches me items where the "email notification sent" message is present.  It does not give me the items where this is not present.

Answer (score 0):

This should make it:

```
(index="cusomerIndex" source=*client-api* "pending customer approval") OR (index="orderIndex" source=*order-api* "email notification sent")
| rex field=_raw "approval for (?<custid>[^\s]+)"
| rex field=_raw "customerId: (?<custid>[^\s]+)"
| transaction custid 
| search NOT "email notification sent"
```